# How to combine two logic actions in one method without infinite render?

Tags: reactjs

I have one method handleNavigate for 'next and previous' buttons action logic. Each action call setState depending on number of selectedStepId. If one of the condition is true, I call setState, component re-renders, i'am again inside handleNavigate method and infinite render occurs. In short, First scenario: I click next -> selectedStepId equals 0 -> setState call (component re-render) -> selectedStepId equals 1.
Second scenario: I click previous -> selectedStepId equals 1 -> setState call(component re-render) -> selectedStepId equals 1.

How to combine logic for both actions and avoid infinite render calls, what is the right condition (or may be lifecycle method), I try to figure out how to achieve this but with no success. I need somehow detect if it was 'next' or 'previous' action occurs and do appropriate logic inside my method. Or it's not possible in my case?

```
Parent component: 
 handleNavigate = () => {
        const { selectedStepId } = this.state
        if (condition ) {
            ...huge amount of logic for 'next' action
        } else {
            ...huge amount of logic for 'previous' action
        }
   return Promise.resolve() //method should return promise (for common component)
}

Child component:
 // Get onNavigate property from parent
   <WizardSteps
   title={currentWizardStepTitle}
   selectedStepId={selectedStepId}
   steps={wizardStepsModel}
   onNavigate={onNavigate}

//onNavigate callback detects all navigation occurs (previous or next)
/>
```

Comment: It sounds like an anti pattern, where do you call your `handleNavigate` function?

Comment: inside my class container component

Comment: Do you mean inside render?

Comment: The problem is my common component use one callback (handleNavigate) and it detects all navigation's occurs (prev or next), depending on it I should use appropriate logic for next and previous actions. No, outside render

Comment: Show us how and where do you call it